# How do I spawn a completely new Process in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to call python functions in sub-processes without creating a copy of the current process.

I have a method `A.run()` which should call `B.run()` multiple times.
`A.run()` consumes a lot of memory, so I don't want to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` because it copies the whole memory AFAIK.
I also do not want to use `subprocess.Popen` because it has several disadvantages to me:

- only pass strings as parameters
- cannot take advantage of exceptions
- I have to know the location of `B.py` exactly, instead of relying on `PYTHONPATH`

I also do not want to spawn threads because `B.run()` crashes easily and I don't want it to effect the parent process.

Is there a way I have overlooked that has the advantage of spawning separate processes, without the extra memory but with the benefits of calling a python method?

Edit 1:
Answers to some questions:

- If I understand this correctly, I don't need the context of the first python process.
- I cannot reuse Processes because I call a C++ library which has static variables and they need to be destroyed.

Comment: Do you want to have context of first python process to be available in new python process ?

Comment: Looking what you are saying your only option is run B on detached threads, and handling whenever they end manually

Comment: Could you create the `ProcessPoolExecutor` before the clostly bits of `A.run`? Maybe create it before `A.run` starts even, and pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Comment: @hamsolo474: I'll try the spawn method which sounds exactly what I want.

Comment: @hamsolo474: do you know if I can achieve the same behaviour in python 2 on unix? It doesn't mention it in the the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Bantak As far as i can tell it works on unix in python 3 but i can't find when the feature was added and you're  right the docs for python 2 don't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Most Unix Operating Systems are using Copy-On-Write when they fork new processes.

This implies that, if the memory is not changed by the process children, the memory is not duplicated but shared.

You see the processes having the same amount of memory due to the fact that they use *that* amount of virtual memory, but when it comes to the physical one, the parent process memory is actually in a unique copy shared among them all.

If I assume right and the children processes are not touching the parent's memory at all, then you're just wasting your time going against Unix design principles.

[More info here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58145/how-does-copy-on-write-in-fork-handle-multiple-fork)